# How to check if multiple variables have same value in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSL where i am getting the values of 6 variables. The 6 variables have an integer value say 3,4 etc. I need to check if all the 6 variables have the same value or not. How can i achieve this in an XSL ? 
My XML is :

```
<records>
    <A>
       <Value> test </Value>
       <Value> test </Value>
       <Value> test </Value>
    </A>
    <B>
       <Value> test </Value>
    </B>
    <C>
       <Value> test </Value>
       <Value> test </Value>
    </C>
    <D>
        <Value> test </Value>
    </D>
    <E>
        <Value> test </Value>
        <Value> test </Value>
    </E>
    <F>
        <Value> test </Value>                        
    </F>
</records>
```

My XSL Looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:variable
    name="noOfANodes"
    select="count(/records/A/*)">
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable
    name="noOfBNodes"
    select="count(/records/B/*)">
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable
    name="noOfCNodes"
    select="count(/records/C/*)">
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable
    name="noOfDNodes"
    select="count(/records/D/*)">
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable
    name="noOfENodes"
    select="count(/records/E/*)">
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable
    name="noOfFNodes"
    select="count(/records/F/*)">
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:choose>
            <!-- The following is obv wrong. -->
            <xsl:when test="$noOfANodes=$noOfBNodes=$noOfCNodes=$noOfDNodes"> 
         </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In xpath you combine multiple tests with the keyword `and`.

In your case, you can rewrite your test as

```
<xsl:when test="$noOfANodes=$noOfBNodes and $noOfBNodes=$noOfCNodes and $noOfCNodes=$noOfDNodes and $noOfDNodes=$noOfENodes and $noOfENodes=$noOfFNodes">
    <!-- Do something here -->
</xsl:when>
```

Here we test pairwise - test the first variable against the second, then test the second against the third (we don't need to test the first against the third, as we know that is true if this test is true), then test the third against the fourth, and so on.

---

If you can use XSLT2, this can even be simplified somewhat to

```
<xsl:when test="every $m in ($noOfANodes,$noOfBNodes,$noOfCNodes,$noOfDNodes,$noOfENodes) satisfies ($m=$noOfFNodes)">
    <!-- Do something here -->
</xsl:when>
```

where we construct a series of each value except the last and check them each against the last.  If all of them are equal to the last, we know that they are all equal to each other.

We actually could have used this same logic in the XSLT1 case, and tested each variable against the last.

Comment: XSLT 2 is a seperate version of xslt? How can i use it ?

Comment: @Chandeep You have to have an XSLT2 processor.  Saxon is one of the most widely used open source ones.  Otherwise, it is just a matter of setting the version on your stylesheet (you already have the version set as 2.0) and understanding the differences between the two versions.  XSLT2 adds some more features and has a few features work differently.

Answer (score 1):

You should use complex conditions like this:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:variable
name="noOfANodes"
select="count(/records/A/*)">
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable
name="noOfBNodes"
select="count(/records/B/*)">
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable
name="noOfCNodes"
select="count(/records/C/*)">
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable
name="noOfDNodes"
select="count(/records/D/*)">
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable
name="noOfENodes"
select="count(/records/E/*)">
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable
name="noOfFNodes"
select="count(/records/F/*)">
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:choose>
        <!-- The following can extend to any number of statements. -->
        <xsl:when test="$noOfANodes=$noOfBNodes and $noOfANodes=$noOfCNodes and $noOfANodes=$noOfDNodes"> 
     </xsl:when>

<xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0 you can write

```
count(distinct-values(($noOfANodes, $noOfBNodes, $noOfCNodes,
 $noOfDNodes, $noOfENodes, $noOfFNodes))) = 1
```

Better still, avoid using six variables:

```
count(distinct-values(/records/*/count(Value))) = 1
```